# Applescript (osascript): opening split panes in iTerm 2 and performing commands

Tags: terminal, applescript, iterm, osascript

The following works to open two *tabs* in [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/split_panes).

I can't seem to figure out how to get this to using split *panes* instead.

I've tried applying what I see on several forums, but it never works. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```applescript
osascript <<-eof
        tell application "iterm"
                set myterm to (make new terminal)
                tell myterm
                        launch session "Default session"
                        tell the last session
                                set name to "Server"
                                write text "cd $projectsFolder"
                        end tell
                        launch session "Default session"
                        tell the last session
                                set name to "Console"
                                write text "cd $projectsFolder"
                        end tell
                end tell
        end tell
eof
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally figured this out.

By sending keystrokes to the application, you can open and navigate split-pane.

```
tell i term application "System Events" to keystroke "D" using command down

tell i term application "System Events" to keystroke "]" using command down
```

An example sending commands to split pane and naming each pane. I use this to start my node application.

```
write text "cd $projectsFolder/$2.m"

write text "/usr/local/bin/frontend.sh $1 $2"

tell i term application "System Events" to keystroke "D" using command down

tell i term application "System Events" to keystroke "]" using command down

set name to "$2.api"

write text "cd $projectsFolder/$2.api"

write text "/usr/local/bin/backend.sh $1 $2"
```

Comment: Did you include the tokens `i term` by accident?

Comment: No, I didn't, @mklement0.

Comment: Thanks; I've since realized that this actually works _when enclosed in a `tell application "iTerm"` block_. I was thrown by the unusual syntax - seems that `iTerm` itself prepends `i term application` to the application name when you compile a `tell application ...` statement inside a `tell application "iTerm"` block. An equivalent form (with an explicit `activate` command to ensure that the keystrokes are sent to `iTerm`) would be: `tell application "iTerm" to activate`, followed by `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "D" using command down`.

Comment: Ah, okay. I haven't actually compiled any of this, it's just included in a bash script I'm working on.

Comment: Got it; if the intent is to return to the _previously active_ pane, you're better off sending `"["` rather than `"]"` - that way, it'll work even when there's already more than 1 pane.

Comment: I encourage you to remove the `i term application` from the `tell i term application "System Events"` statements: your code will run without them and, most importantly, will continue to run if/when the underlying problem is fixed in `iTerm` (as I said: AppleScript editor _will_ insert the `i term application` when you compile, but that doesn't apply in your case, since you're passing source code directly to `osascript`).

Answer (score 34):

With the new nightly build it is quite nice. It seems to be missing in the public version, although it was implemented about a year ago:
[Source - AppleScriptTest.m](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/master/sources/AppleScriptTest.m)

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    select first window
    
    # Create new tab
    tell current window
        create tab with default profile
    end tell
    
    # Split pane
    tell current session of current window
        split vertically with default profile
        split vertically with default profile
    end tell
    
    # Exec commands
    tell first session of current tab of current window
        write text "cd ~/Developer/master-node"
        write text "coffee"
    end tell
    tell second session of current tab of current window
        write text "gulp w"
    end tell
    tell third session of current tab of current window
    end tell
end tell
```

I had to search way too long for this, so maybe I can help somebody out with this (probably myself in a couple of weeks), because this was one of the first things I found. This solution even works with activated focus-follows-mouse, which is missing in the other answers.

Comment: This worked for me. I did have to change `select first terminal window` to `select first window`

Comment: Pasted the exact code into apple script editor and it gives me "error "iTerm got an error: Can’t get current window of window id 35415." number -1728 from current window of window id 35415"

Comment: Confirmed this still works on macOS 12.6, and edited the example to apply the fix suggested by @DennisBest

Answer (score 11):

As Dom pointed out, in the new 2.9 beta builds, the other answers won't work anymore. I was frustrated by not being able to automated this so I wrote a teamocil compatible command line tool that does exactly this:

https://github.com/TomAnthony/itermocil

It allows you to write YAML files for pre-configured sets of windows and panes, which can run pre-defined sets of commands for the given project.

Comment: many thanks !!

<!-- language: lang-applescript -->
tell application "iTerm"
 create window with default profile
 tell current session of current window
  write text "bash itermocil log"
 end tell
end tell
<--

Answer (score 5):

<sup>**Update**: iTerm2 **v3** has **much-improved, but incompatible AppleScript support** - see https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html</sup>

To provide some background to @Joel's own answer:

iTerm 2's AppleScript support (as of iTerm 2 v1.0.0.201306220):

- is **incomplete**: there is no support to script *split panes* - hence the OP is resorting to the suboptimal technique of sending keystrokes.
- exhibits some **bizarre behavior**: when *compiling* (in AppleScript Editor) a `tell "System Events" ...` statement inside a `tell application "iTerm"` block, the prefix `i term application` is inexplicably inserted before the `"System Events"` - since the code below is not precompiled, this prefix is *not* included so as to avoid problems in the future.
- has **bugs / is inconsistent with its dictionary**: what the dictionary describes as the `exec` command - which doesn't actually work - is in reality fulfilled by the `write text` command: it executes the argument passed or - if the argument has a trailing space - simply "types" the argument without submitting it.

Here's the solution with split panes based on the workaround (sending keystrokes) - a `bash` script invoking AppleScript code via `osascript`:

Limitations, due to panes not being part of the dictionary:

- the other pane that is opened cannot be named
- no command can be sent to the other pane

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/env bash

projectFolder="$HOME/Desktop" # example
osascript <<-EOF
  tell application "iTerm"
    tell (make new terminal) # Create a new pseudo terminal...
      tell (launch session "Default session") # ... and open a session (window)
        # Name the new window (its original pane).
        set name to "Server"
        # Execute the 'cd' command in the original pane.
        write text "cd '$projectFolder'"
        # Create a new split pane, horizontally, by sending ⌘⇧-D 
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "d" using {shift down, command down}
          # !! Note: We canNOT:
          #  - name this pane separately
          #  - execute a command in it.
        # Return to the original pane, by sending ⌘-[ 
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "[" using {command down}
      end tell
    end tell
  end tell
EOF
```

Comment: Mostly correct @mklement0, but you can name each pan and send keystrokes to the other pane. I updated above.

Comment: @Joel: Hmmm... That doesn't work for me. Looking at the *logic* of your updated code, you perform _all_ your operations in the _original_ pane (since the `name` and the other group of `write` commands are performed after sending ⌘-], which causes you to return to the _original_ pane). Am I missing something? What `iTerm` version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

starting from @mklement0, this is my script that open a new tab, split in 4 panels and run comands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
osascript <<-EOF
    set cmds to {"rabbitmq-server", "mongod", "redis-server", "htop"}

    tell application "iTerm"
        activate
        set myterm to (current terminal)

        tell myterm
            launch session "Default Session"

            # split vertically
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "d" using command down
            delay 1
            # previus panel
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "[" using command down
            delay 1
            # split horizontally
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "d" using {shift down, command down}
            delay 1
            # next panel
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "]" using command down
            delay 1
            # split horizontally
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "d" using {shift down, command down}

            set n to count of cmds
            repeat with i from 1 to n
                # next panel
                tell application "System Events" to keystroke "]" using command down
                delay 1
                tell the current session to write text (item i of cmds)
            end repeat
        end tell

    end tell  
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it's helpful: I have the similar problem of wanting a key combo shortcut in iTerm to split panes and have the new pane inherit the title of the original session. I came up with the following, which solves that problem and relies less on sending keystrokes (though I'd love to eliminate them entirely).

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell the current terminal
        tell the current session
            set the_name to get name
            tell i term application "System Events" to keystroke "d" using {command down, shift down}
        end tell

        tell the current session
            set name to the_name
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I am using BetterTouchTool to bind a key combo -- namely, `cmd+'` -- to the execution of this AppleScript. (I find that it gets screwy for some key combos, I would naively guess because you are effectively holding that key combo down on top of whatever keystrokes the script sends. I haven't chased down how to define the keyboard shortcut in the preferences of iTerm itself. I suspect that might mitigate the issue.)